# Why do I get an error when I put the cors:true option back in to serverless.yml?

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

To test that I needed CORS enabled in my API Gateway for a Lambda Proxy, I removed the `cors:true` definition in my serverless.yml.

Then when I put it back, I get the following error:

> You can only use "origin" or "origins", but not both at the same time to configure CORS. Please check the docs for more info.

I cant find anything in the docs that would explain why my code would be throwing that error.
I know that the single line version is synonomous with a multi line version like so:

```
cors:
            origins:
              - '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
            allowCredentials: false
```

as per: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#enabling-cors

Does it perhaps cache the config and now it thinks Im declaring it twice, once as 'origin' and another as 'origins'.

I can't see why I would get that error if I just toggled the `cors:true' line between deploys as I did.

This is from my serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  submitApi:
    handler: handler.submit
    description: Cloud API integration to the Third-Party API
    events:
      - http:
          path: thirdParty
          method: post
          cors: true
```

**Update**:
This issue appears to be a bug that is being tracked in the serverless project, found here:  https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6098

Comment: Im not really sure why this worked, but I switched it to the long form and the build completed succesfully

Comment: Interesting - this just started happening to me today too. I wonder if there's a bug in the latest release.

Comment: Yep - see this issue: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6098

Comment: funny though, with the verbose config, Im getting a cors error anyway